# Need help interpreting an ODEs problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem on ODEs that confuses me. The problem statement is:

> Let $X(t)$ be a fundamental matrix of $$x'(t) = A(t)x(t), \tag{1}$$
>   where $A(t + \omega) = A(t)$ for some $\omega > 0$.  Define $P(\omega)$ to be the set of all solutions to (1).     Suppose $f\in C(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is a function such that $f(t + \omega) = f(t)$ for all $t$.  Show that the following are equivalent:
>
> (1) The equation $x'(t) = A(t)x(t) + f(t)$ has a unique solution.
>
> (2) $X^{-1}(\omega) - X^{-1}(0)$ is non-singular.
>
> (3) $\dim(P(\omega)) = 0$.

---

I think that $(1)\Leftrightarrow (3)$ is trivial.  But $(2)$ confuses me.  If $X$ is a fundamental matrix, its columns must each be solutions to $x'(t) = A(t)x(t)$, which means the unique solution from the first condition wouldn't be unique since it could be added to any multiple of any column of $X(t)$ which would generate a new solution to $x'(t) = A(t)x(t) + f(t)$.

The only way this problem would be avoided is if $X(t)$  had non non-zero columns which would make (2) a nonsense statement.

What's my logic error here?